# Getting Error -"insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service " during Split File

Tags: filestream

I am trying to split large data file(4 GB) in multiple files.

I am getting below error:

> insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service

How can I remove this?

Comment: You should tag this question with whatever language you're using, and also provide the code that's causing the error (and specify which line in particular).

Comment: when i am trying to write the split file (1 GB Data) then i am getting the error.                                outputFile.Write(Headerbuffer, 0, HeaderLoc + 1); in headerbuffer around 966367641 byte data are passing.